# How to upgrade to a release candidate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm on Rails 4.0.4.

I would like to try out the latest relase candidate for 4.1.

How would I upgrade my Rails application to the latest RC?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can run `bundle update` to update all your gems at once.

If you just want to update a particular gem (such as rails) you can run `bundle update rails`.

Comment: Would a simple `bundle update rails` really update to release candidates as well?

Comment: I'm not sure.  They do have a stable release already.  If that doesn't work you can just put the version you want in your Gemfile and run bundle install.

Answer (score 0):

If a gem's version number has a letter in the version then it is considered to be 'pre-release' and will be skipped by `bundler` unless you specify otherwise in your `Gemfile`.

If you want to use a pre-release version of a gem:

```
# Gemfile
gem "rspec-rails", ">= 6.0.0-rc1", "< 6.1"
```

This will install `6.0.0-rc1` and then update to anything in the `6.0.x` releases (I think this includes future pre-releases) using the RubyGems [pessimistic version constraints](https://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#pessimistic-version-constraint).

[Source](https://makandracards.com/makandra/498416-pre-releasing-a-ruby-gem)